# Column alias is not recognized

Tags: sql, postgresql, having-clause, column-alias

This minimal example is supposed to extract year from time stamps, then count something in a given year.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rental_ts) as year,
       COUNT(DISTINCT rental_id)
FROM rental
GROUP BY year
HAVING year=2020
```

Running it, I get an error `column "year" does not exist`. What is the reason for this?

- Code with explicit `HAVING EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rental_ts)=2020` works without problems, but not very convenient.
- Same would happen if I use `year` in `WHERE` clause instead.
- I practice in [this playground](https://sqlpad.io/playground/). It uses PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, that is true.  Column aliases are not allowed.  One solution is to repeat the expression:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rental_ts) as year,
       COUNT(DISTINCT rental_id)
FROM rental
GROUP BY year
HAVING EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rental_ts) = 2020;
```

A better solution is to filter *before* aggregating:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rental_ts) as year,
       COUNT(DISTINCT rental_id)
FROM rental
WHERE rental_ts >= '2020-01-01' AND rental_ts < '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY year;
```

This is better for two reasons.  First, it is index (and partition) compatible.  Second, it reduces the amount of data needed for the aggregation.

Comment: Quick question: filter before aggregating = use WHERE? Also, did you mean `HAVING EXTRACT(YEAR FROM rental_ts) =2020` in the first example & the last line is not needed in the 2nd example? Thanks!

Comment: @icemtel . . . I fixed the logic.